# Multiple items in one objectStore

Tags: html, indexeddb, jaydata

I am trying to do simple application with Indexed DB. I want to store multiple items in one objectStore. Is it possible? I tried something like that, but it does not work:

```
    itemsDB.indexedDB.addTodo = function(Name, Desp) {
    var db = itemsDB.indexedDB.db;
    var trans = db.transaction(['items'], IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE);
    var store = trans.objectStore("items");

    var data = {
      "name": Name,
      "description": Desp, 

    };

    var request = store.put(data);
   }
```

I have used sample from http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Targetting "just" IndexedDB will narrow down your compatible clients to chrome and firefox users. Have a look at [JayData](http://jaydata.org), it supports your object store pattern with an option of fallback provider list: if the client has IndexedDB it will be used but if only WebSQL what the client has (95% of the mobile devices) then webSQL will be used.

Also the syntax is much easier for storing or retrieving, check the [ToDo list example](http://examples.jaydata.org/Todolist2/index.html), this also shows the fallback provider option.

Answer (score 1):

IndexedDB object stores were designed to house multiple objects and let you cursor across their attributes.

It's not clear exactly what's causing your `put` issue but if you have a key on either `name` or `description` it's going to just replace an existing object rather than add a new one. You'd want to use `add` instead of `put`.

One thing to keep in mind about the HTML5Rocks examples is that currently they will only work in Chrome (which happens to have a lagging IndexedDB implementation).

FWIW, a small tip is that there's an error in your JavaScript here (extra comma after Desp var) which might prevent it from running in IE10:

```
var data = {
      "name": Name,
      "description": Desp, 

    };
```